# Backbone fetch doesn't work as expected

Tags: backbone.js

When I call `fetch` on my collection the app is calling the server and server returns an array of object. In the success function of the fetch call I've got an empty collection and the original response holding all objects that was responded by the server.

**Collection**

```
var OpenOrders = BaseCollection.extend({
    model: Order,
    url: baseUrl + '/api/orders?status=1'
});
```

**Model**

```
var Order = BaseModel.extend(

    {
        url:baseUrl + "/api/order",
        defaults:{
            order_items: new OrderList(),
            location: 1,
            remark: "remark"
        },

        initialize: function(options) {

            var orderItems = this.get('order_items');
            if (orderItems instanceof Array) {
                orderItems = new OrderList(orderItems);
                this.set({'order_items': orderItems})
            }
            orderItems.bind('change', _.bind(function() {
                this.trigger('change')
            }, this))
                .bind('remove', _.bind(function() {
                this.trigger('change')
            }, this));
            return this;
        },

    sum: function() {
        return  this.get('order_items').sum();
    },

    validate: function() {
        return !!this.get('order_items').length;
    },

    add:function(product) {
        this.get('order_items').add(product);

    },
    remove: function(product) {
        this.get('order_items').remove(product);

    }
);
```

**Fetching the collection**

```
this.collection.fetch({success:_.bind( function(collection, response){
            console.log('OpenOrdersListView', collection.toJSON())
            // logs []
            console.log('OpenOrdersListView', response)
            // logs [Object, Object ...]

        }, this)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damm, its the `validate` method in my model. I've though validate have to return a boolean, but after reading the [docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate), it has to return an error message only if the model is not valid.

```
 validate: function() {
         if (!this.get('order_items').length){
             return 'set minium of one product before save the order'
         }
    },
```